# Layout XML is not loading from layout-sw600dp folder

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-layout

In my application i have a layout `test.xml` file in `layout-hdpi` and `layout-sw600dp` folder...
When i run the application in `Samsung Tab GT-P1000` the layout is always loading from `layout-hdpi` folder but it should load from `layout-sw600dp`...what is the solution for this...what is the exact folder name to load layouts in `Samsung Tab GT-P1000` or in 7 inch Tablets...Moreover the Samsung Tab GT-P1000 having the version 2.3....

Comment: dont use layout-hdpi folder use layout folder your tablet is getting confused i guess

Comment: the app should work in mobiles also..if i remove the hdpi folder then what is the folder for the mobile devices to load the xml files...

Comment: layout folder obviously well using layout and layout-sw600dp worked for my project

Comment: may be your version is higher than 2.3...

Comment: it is 19 android 4.4 kitkat

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), `sw<N>dp` folders (smallest width) were added in API 13. Therefore Android 2.3 won't be able to use those folders.

Comment: Yes i read it...so what is the solution for loading the xmls in Tablets having the versions below 2.3..

Comment: tablets came from honeycomb version so I dont think its possible

Comment: @Vamshi You could try `layout-large` or `layout-xlarge` but it may or may not work, depending on your tablet.

Comment: @  Illegal Argument Samsung Tab GT-P1000 comes with Android OS, v2.2 (Froyo)

Comment: @Vamshi Well, you can only work with what you have available. Android didn't really have much support for tablets before 3.0 and this is one of the places where it shows.